# Add class to all child labels in each parent div using label count in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to add class to all child labels in each parent div using label count in parent div.

I have a radio buttons group code generated dynamically, so i cant add static classes using html

using this classes i need to append another div in the labels as label helper text.

```
<div class="radioTable">
 <div>
    <span>
       <label></label>
   </span>
</div>
 <div>
    <span>
       <label></label>
   </span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="radioTable">
 <div>
    <span>
       <label></label>
   </span>
</div>
 <div>
    <span>
       <label></label>
   </span>
</div>
 <div>
    <span>
       <label></label>
   </span>
</div>
</div>
```

want to add class using jquery like this:

```
<div class="radioTable">
 <div>
    <span>
       <label class="radioLabel-1"></label>
   </span>
</div>
 <div>
    <span>
       <label class="radioLabel-2"></label>
   </span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="radioTable">
 <div>
    <span>
       <label class="radioLabel-1"></label>
   </span>
</div>
 <div>
    <span>
       <label class="radioLabel-2"></label>
   </span>
</div>
 <div>
    <span>
       <label class="radioLabel-3"></label>
   </span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to target the specific fields and [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop through them to add relevant class like the following way:

```js
var parents = document.querySelectorAll('.radioTable');
Array.from(parents).forEach(function(p){
  var labels = p.querySelectorAll('label');
  var classPre = 'radioLabel-';
  Array.from(labels).forEach(function(l, i){
    l.classList.add(classPre + (i+1));
  });
});
```

```css
.radioLabel-1{ color:#00cc00 }
.radioLabel-2{ color:#ff0000 }
.radioLabel-3{ color:#0000ff }
```

```html
<div class="radioTable">
 <div>
    <span>
       <label>RadioLabel-1</label>
   </span>
</div>
 <div>
    <span>
       <label>RadioLabel-2</label>
   </span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="radioTable">
 <div>
    <span>
       <label>RadioLabel-1</label>
   </span>
</div>
 <div>
    <span>
       <label>RadioLabel-2</label>
   </span>
</div>
 <div>
    <span>
       <label>RadioLabel-3</label>
   </span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the out put shows is adding classes like 1,2,3,4,5.

Comment: i want it to be classes to be like, 1,2 the again 1,2,3

Comment: @Praveen, please check the updated code, I have added some style as well for the visible difference:)

Comment: i have fixed code for as per your requirement. please check. @praveen
output will be show in inspect -> elements.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do something like this.

```
$("div.radioTable span > label").each(function(index) {
  $(this).addClass(`radioLabel-${index + 1}`);
});
```

Also, if you want it to restart the increment for every radioTable, you can do the following. That being said, there may be a more performant solution.

```
$("div.radioTable").each(function() {
  $(this).find("span > label").each(function(index) {
    $(this).addClass(`radioLabel-${index + 1}`)
  });
});
```

Comment: Your solution is the simplest, I believe.. you just need to add 1 to the `index` so it doesn't start at 0. Great job!

Comment: Updated to start at 1 instead of 0. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I add script to add class

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("div.radioTable").each(function(index, item) {
debugger;
 $("label", item).each(function(indexx,itemm){
 $(this).addClass("radioLabel-"+ (indexx + 1));
 //console.log( index + ": " + $(this).text() );
 })
 
});

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radioTable">
 <div>
    <span>
       <label></label>
   </span>
</div>
 <div>
    <span>
       <label></label>
   </span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="radioTable">
 <div>
    <span>
       <label></label>
   </span>
</div>
 <div>
    <span>
       <label></label>
   </span>
</div>
 <div>
    <span>
       <label></label>
   </span>
</div>
</div>
```